# Can't search for a file i know is in sharepoint

Tags: search

I am looking to determine the best way to organize my specific area of SharePoint, so I have placed files in directories. So basically I know where the file is, but when I type a string of characters I know is in the file name, the search does not find it. it has been 5 hours and still no search results. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the Crawl duration you have for Search ? Try once with full search crawl.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to make are are true before you get any results.

1. The indexer must have crawled the site before any new results are found. Simply waiting may not be enough or is not sufficient to ensure that the indexer ran. The indexer does tend to break sometimes. If you have access to central administration you can go check there and select the content source and make sure it has been indexed recently.
2. Searching for a string in a word will not return results. You need to search for complete words. Try searching for a word in the title of the document. If the document name is "My document" and you search for docum (which is substring of document) then it will not return results.
3. You must have access to the item you're